# What exactly Non DFS Used means?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

This is what I saw on Web UI recently

```
 Configured Capacity     :   232.5 GB
 DFS Used    :   112.44 GB
 Non DFS Used    :   119.46 GB
 DFS Remaining   :   613.88 MB
 DFS Used%   :   48.36 %
 DFS Remaining%  :   0.26 %
```

and I'm so confused that non-dfs Used takes up more than half of capacity,

which I think means half of hadoop storage is being wasted

After spending meaningless time searching, I just formatted namenode, and started from scratch.

And then I copied one huge text file(about 19gigabytes) from local to HDFS (successed).

Now the UI says

```
Configured Capacity  :   232.5 GB
DFS Used     :   38.52 GB
Non DFS Used     :   45.35 GB
DFS Remaining    :   148.62 GB
DFS Used%    :   16.57 %
DFS Remaining%   :   63.92 %
```

before copying, DFS Used and Non DFS Used were both 0.

Because DFS Used is approximately double the original text file size and I configured 2 copy,

I guess that DFS Used is composed up of 2 copies of original and meta.

But still I don't have any idea where Non DFS Used came from and why is that takes up so much capcity more than DFS Used.

What happend? Did I made mistake?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

"Non DFS used" is calculated by following formula:

Non DFS Used = Configured Capacity - Remaining Space - DFS Used

It is still confusing, at least for me.

Because 
**Configured Capacity = Total Disk Space - Reserved Space.**

So **Non DFS used = ( Total Disk Space - Reserved Space) - Remaining Space - DFS Used**

Let's take a example. Assuming I have 100 GB disk, and I set the reserved space (dfs.datanode.du.reserved) to 30 GB.

In the disk, the system and other files used up to 40 GB, DFS Used 10 GB. If you run df -h
, you will see the available space is 50GB for that disk volume.

In HDFS web UI, it will show

**Non DFS used = 100GB(Total) - 30 GB( Reserved) - 10 GB (DFS used) - 50GB(Remaining)
             = 10 GB**

So it actually means, you initially configured to reserve 30G for non dfs usage, and 70 G for HDFS. However,  it turns out non dfs usage exceeds the 30G reservation and eat up 10 GB space which should belongs to HDFS!

The term "Non DFS used" should really be renamed to something like **"How much configured DFS capacity are occupied by non dfs use"**

And one should stop try to figure out why the non dfs use are so high inside hadoop.

One useful command is `lsof | grep delete`, which will help you identify those open file which has been deleted.  Sometimes, Hadoop processes (like hive, yarn, and mapred and hdfs) may hold reference to those already deleted files. And these references will occupy disk space.

Also `du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10` helps list the top ten largest folders.

Comment: Can I empty non-dfs data? If yes how?

Comment: @Mahesha999: try restart datanode.

Comment: "Remaining" in the UI clearly isn't the total remaining space on the whole disk, at least in my case. I have a 315GB disk and 200GB reserved. The UI is showing 26GB DFS (confirmed with `df -h`), 21GB non-DFS, and 68GB remaining, while in fact the disk still has 266GB free !

Comment: Note: I'm running Hadoop 2.7.2

Answer (score 7):

Non DFS used is any data in the filesystem of the data node(s) that isn't in `dfs.data.dirs`.  This would include log files, mapreduce shuffle output and local copies of data files (if you put them on a data node). Use `du` or a similar tool to see whats taking up the space in your filesystem.

Comment: This is incorrect, especially when `dfs.data.dirs` is on separate filesystems from that of `/`. The correct definition is: any data that is not written by HDFS in the same filesystem(s) as the `dfs.data.dirs`. In other words, if you use `hdfs dfs` commands to copy data, then it "DFS usage", and if you use `cp` command to copy files into `dfs.data.dirs`, then it will become "non-DFS usage".

Comment: Can I empty non-dfs data? If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

The correct simplified definition is: "Any data that is not written by HDFS in the same filesystem(s) as the `dfs.data.dirs`. In other words, if you use `hdfs dfs` commands to copy data, it ends up under `dfs.data.dirs` but then it is considered "DFS usage", and if you use regular `cp` command to copy files into `dfs.data.dirs`, then it will become "non-DFS usage".

Answer (score 1):

One more thing.
`Non DFS used =
100GB(Total) - 30 GB( Reserved) - 10 GB (DFS used) - 50GB(Remaining) 
= 10 GB`
Because ext3/ext4 default reserve 5% (refer to reserved block count ), so it should be
`Non DFS used = 
100GB(Total) - 30 GB( Reserved from App) - 5 GB(Reserved from FS) - 10 GB (DFS used) - 50GB(Remaining) 
= 5 GB`

From `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdm1` get the "Reserved block count"
BTW, `tune2fs -m 0.2 /dev/sdm1` to tune the reserved space.

Answer (score 0):

The non-dfs will be some cache files that will be stored by the node manager. You can check the path under yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs property in the yarn-site.xml

You can refer to 
the default [yarn-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) for details.