# HDFS Configured Capacity is lesser than the original disk capacity as per dfsadmin command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I have implemented 2 node cluster using Cloudera Manager 5.4.1 in VMWare workstation and this includes components like Hbase, Impala, Hive, Sqoop2, Oozie, Zookeeper, NameNode, SecondaryName and YARN.
I have simulated 3 disk drives per node which includes sda for OS , sdb & sdc for Hadoop storage.

As I had allocated sdb1 having 16GB and sdc1 having 16GB  dedicated for Hadoop storage on each of the nodes. Hence I assume that my total capacity for HDFS storage including both nodes should be 64GB. But when checked the output using dfsadmin command and also using NameNode UI, I see that the "Configured Capacity is lesser than my original disk size allocated for HDFS".
I have shown the output of dfsadmin command below and also output of df -h is shown. Kindly help me understand why the Configured capacity is showing lesser than my original disk size ?

```
[hduser@node1 ~]$ df -h


Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_node1-LogVol00   40G   15G   23G  39% /
tmpfs                          3.9G   76K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                      388M   39M  329M  11% /boot
/dev/sdb1                       16G  283M   15G   2% /disks/disk1/hdfsstorage/dfs
/dev/sdc1                       16G  428M   15G   3% /disks/disk2/hdfsstorage/dfs
/dev/sdb2                      8.1G  147M  7.9G   2% /disks/disk1/nonhdfsstorage
/dev/sdc2                      8.1G  147M  7.9G   2% /disks/disk2/nonhdfsstorage
cm_processes                   3.9G  5.8M  3.9G   1% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
[hduser@node1 ~]$


[hduser@node1 zookeeper]$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -report
[sudo] password for hduser:
Configured Capacity: 47518140008 (44.25 GB)
Present Capacity: 47518140008 (44.25 GB)
DFS Remaining: 46728742571 (43.52 GB)
DFS Used: 789397437 (752.83 MB)
DFS Used%: 1.66%
Under replicated blocks: 385
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (2):

Name: 192.168.52.111:50010 (node1.example.com)
Hostname: node1.example.com
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 23759070004 (22.13 GB)
DFS Used: 394702781 (376.42 MB)
Non DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 23364367223 (21.76 GB)
DFS Used%: 1.66%
DFS Remaining%: 98.34%
Configured Cache Capacity: 121634816 (116 MB)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 121634816 (116 MB)
Cache Used%: 0.00%
Cache Remaining%: 100.00%
Xceivers: 2
Last contact: Sun May 15 18:15:33 IST 2016


Name: 192.168.52.112:50010 (node2.example.com)
Hostname: node2.example.com
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 23759070004 (22.13 GB)
DFS Used: 394694656 (376.41 MB)
Non DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 23364375348 (21.76 GB)
DFS Used%: 1.66%
DFS Remaining%: 98.34%
Configured Cache Capacity: 523239424 (499 MB)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 523239424 (499 MB)
Cache Used%: 0.00%
Cache Remaining%: 100.00%
Xceivers: 2
Last contact: Sun May 15 18:15:32 IST 2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the configuration

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
  <value>0</value>
  <description>Reserved space in bytes per volume. Always leave this much space free for non dfs use.
  </description>
</property>
```

The reserved space is not part of 'Configured Capacity'.

Comment: Thanks Waltersu. Yes as per the property "dfs.datanode.du.reserved", it was configured to use 4.25 GB and hence I consider now that 4.25 GB is allocated for each data directory in a given node. Since I had two data directory partitions, the reserved space was 8.5 GB per node and which brings the configured capacity on each node to be 23.5 GB (32GB - 8.5GB) 
                                   
I arrived at the formula:
Configured Capacity = Total Disk Space allocated for Data Directories (dfs.data.dir) - Reserved Space for Non DFS Use (dfs.datanode.du.reserved)

Comment: My "Non DFS used" in the cluster has grown upto 400MB and if you can tell me what exactly is "Non DFS used" and how to delete it, it would be of great help. There are some answers in stack overflow, but still am unable to understand.

Comment: [what-exactly-non-dfs-used-means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477983/what-exactly-non-dfs-used-means) has great answers. I have only 2 possible approach in my mind:1. close the process that holds the file handlers to the deleted files. 2. Asume /mnt/disk0/ is your mount point, /mnt/disk0/dfs/ is your configured dataDir, are you sure there's no other files on the disk? like /mnt/disk0/otherDir/otherFile. Try delete it.