# Why is my hdfs capacity not remainng constant?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I am running a pyspark job on dataproc and my total hdfs capacity is not remaining constant.

[image]

As you can see in the first chart that the remaining hdfs capacity is falling even though the used hdfs capacity is minimal. Why is remaining + used not constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "used" in the monitoring graph is actually "DFS used", and it didn't show "non-DFS used". If you open the HDFS UI in the component gateway web interfaces you should be able to see something like:

```
Configured Capacity  :   232.5 GB
DFS Used     :   38.52 GB
Non DFS Used     :   45.35 GB
DFS Remaining    :   148.62 GB
DFS Used%    :   16.57 %
DFS Remaining%   :   63.92 %
```

The formula is :

**DFS Remaining = Total Disk Space - max(Reserved Space, Non-DFS Used) - DFS Used**

**Configured capacity = Total Disk Space - Reserved Space**

Reserved Space is controlled by the `dfs.datanode.du.reserved` [1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) property which defaults to 0. So in your case it is the non-DFS used that gets deducted. Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477983/what-exactly-non-dfs-used-means).